# Field labels on repeated grids - Orbeon night-build

Tags: repeat, orbeon

I'm new to both Orbeon and XForms and please forgive me for asking help on a version not yet released.

I am building an application that requires repeated blocks with multiple fields. The client wants to be able to use the form builder in the future to update the forms so manual xforms programming is out of question. At the moment I am using the night-built version of orbeon which supports repeatable grid, hoping that it will be included in the next release soon.

A problem I ran into is the lack of support of labels inside the grid. The forms builder does not allow input of lables to the fields. When I manually edit the source and put in the labels in the resources section, the labels are not visible except the first row of fields.

My first question is whether this is the intended behavior for the eventual release version? If so would it be possible to make it overridable by using a runner property?

Now the client is willing to accept some minor editing in the source code. Is there a simple way to make the (mnually input) labels visible? Some CSS code perhaps?

All information would be much appreciated.

regards,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

This is not the intended behavior. As you have noted the new builder is not yet in a stable version and the code is very much in flux at this time.

The idea is that if each repeated group of rows contains only one row, then the labels of the fields will appear as table headers. This is the behavior of the current Form Runner repeater. See for example:

[image]

Now if a repeated group contains more than one row, then the labels of the controls *should* probably be within the grid cells themselves, as it doesn't make sense to put the labels in table headers in this case. But note that this scenario is not implemented yet.